# 500 internal server error in codeigniter csrf with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

i'm using codeigniter 2.2 and working with signup form. I'm using  ajax to validate username. i have enabled CSRF protection in codeigniter , after enabling CSRF i'm getting 500 Internal Server error, i have attached a image about this problem.

i think there could be some problem in my jquery

```
             var cct = $("input[name=byzero_crack_stocks]").val();               
              $.ajax({
                 type: "post",
                 url: url+"ajax_register/username_check_ajax",
                  data: {
                       'username':$("#username").val(),
                        'csrf_token_name':cct,
                       },
```

but i can't  find out.Help me out here.[image]

Comment: Server error.log may give you some clues.

Comment: Codeigniter throws a 500 for a variety of different reasons. Can you track down a more specific error message somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

add csrf token to data before posting

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url+"ajax_register/username_check_ajax",
            data: {'<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>':'<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>','username':$("#username").val()}

        })
```

csrf token needs to be send along every request so it needs to be specified by the above echo statements